# Retriving values of pid stored in cookie in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, shopping-cart

i am working on a shopping project. And what I want to do is to store the Product ID's (pid) of  the products for which user clicks on "add to cart"

I have this kind html code on all products which calls a servlet **"Cart.java"**, with their respective pIDs:

```
Product1: <a href=Cart?product=1>add to cart?</a> //here 1 is the pid
Product2: <a href=Cart?product=2>add to cart?</a> //here 2 is the pid
```

A single page has multiple products and there are different pages associated with different kind of products (The pages are dynamically created using JDBC).

What I want is for all the products on which user has clicked **"add to cart"**, the pid gets stored somewhere (I am using cookies for that because I thought it would work.. will it?)
and later I should be able to get all those PID's on another page (when user clicks on **"Take me to my cart"**) so that I could display their details from the DB and ask the user if he wants to buy them.

The **"take me to my cart"** hyperlink calls another servlet ViewCart:

```
<a href="ViewCart">Take me to my cart</a>
```

The cookie code on servlet **cart.java** is:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String id=request.getParameter("product").trim();
Cookie ck=new Cookie("pid",id);//creating cookie object
response.addCookie(ck);
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("product.jsp");
rd.include(request, response);
}
```

"product.jsp" is the page on which products are displayed.

The code on servlet **ViewCart.java** is:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Cookie ck[]=request.getCookies();
        for(Cookie i: ck)
        {
            if(i.getName().equals("pid"))
            out.print(ck.toString()+"</br>");
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("cart.jsp");
        rd.include(request, response);
}
```

But this is not working I am a beginner so don't know if I am doing it wrong. And I also want to destroy the values in the cookie as soon as the user logs out. Also tell me if not cookies what else should i use?

I think i messed up everything. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better pick up a framework to avoid reinventing the wheel and learning from mistakes that others already made and learned from. Anyway, there's no need to mess with cookies and going so low level. Just attach a Cart object to the current session and you're done:

```
public class Cart {
  public void addItem(String id, Integer quantity) {}
  public Integer getItemQuantity(String id) {}
  public Map<String, Integer> getAllItems() {}
}
```

Then you have the servlet that adds an item to the cart (you'd better use POST for requests that change the application state):

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  HttpSession session = req.getSession();
  Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");
  if (cart == null) {
    cart = new Cart();
    session.setAttribute("cart", cart)
  };
  String id = req.getParamter("id");
  Integer quantity = Integer.parseInt(req.getParamter("quantity"));
  cart.addItem(id, quantity);
  // write your response
}
```

and finally your `ViewCartServlet`

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
  Cart cart = (Cart) req.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
  if (cart != null) {
    // print items
  } else {
    // print an error
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You can add whatever method you want to the Cart class, getItem(), getTotalPrice(), you name it. req.getSession() gives you the HttpSession for the current user, and you can put and get Cart objects to/from it

Comment: No, I'm asking what's the problem with my answer because I cannot make it simpler than that. Your users have a session, sessions have a cart, and two servlets are provided to put items in the cart and seeing its content